# Datepicker inside responsive table

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have datepicker inside reponsive table. Because i open this at mobile, so i think overflow-x:auto is a must, because it maybe have many columns.
When i click the input date, i cant see datepicker, its blocked by the table.

What should i do to make the datepicker popup can over the top of its table?
I think it could be done by CSS only

Ask me if my explaination is not clear.
Thanks

I want to see my datepicker
CSS only

Comment: You'll probably want to look into something like position: absolute; in combination with z-index. Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your code if you need further help.

Comment: You provide no code or specifics (whether you're using 3rd-party libraries). Hard to help you. But yes, probably as a rudimentary trick, you'd use `position:fixed` on the popup as a starting point, maybe. There's also this excellent library: [Floating UI](https://floating-ui.com). Personally I'd try to introduce logic at the click, determine conditions, and if a narrow viewport, override the original popup, and pass the data into a proper dialog to the user.

Comment: Side note: Your table actually isn't "responsive" if you simply let it overflow off the screen. For narrow viewports, truly responsive tables transform into a linear list with no columns, perhaps with complete rows displayed as nicely formatted cards (like browsing products) and sort controls occur in a dialog. There simply is not enough real estate to _pleasantly_ show large tables in narrow viewports.

Comment: I'm sorry, but its hard for to provide the code. but what i want is, how to make something like that in the right way, so things like that dont happen